# Unable to create flirt signature for ida pro

Tags: ida

I am trying to create the flit signature file for zlib library. My flair version 6.1 .I am using the following command:

```
$ ./pelf libz.a zlib.pat
Output: skipped:0 total:0 

$ ./sigmake zlib.pat zzlib.sig
Output: No headers found.
```

The problem is that pelf is not parsing the `libz.a` file. The same problem is occuring when I try to parse another file i.e `libgcc.a`

Comment: Where did you get libz.a?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Windows user, but if I'm not mistaken Linux AR/COFF (static library) files are .a where as on Windows they're .lib

If this is the case, then you need to use plb instead of pelf. I believe ELF is the format used for executables, not code objects, on Linux (the equivalent of Windows' PE files, .exe and .dll)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the static library (`libz.a` in this case) is formatted correctly.

I would suggest using the `nm` tool to examine the symbols in the library.

```
nm libz.a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using file command in linux to verify it's an elf file.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Once you reach 50 reputation you'll be able to comment on answers. untill then, reserve answers only for what you know will fix their problem.